# Linux Raid Installation: how to see, how many disks are being used on Raid

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora

I have installed Ubuntu on multiple disks with Raid.

- How can I check, how many disks are being used for raid?
- How can I check, if all disks are healthy?
- How can I check, if any disk is being taken out or being defected?

**Thanks guys for your kindly and gently feedback or improving my understanding.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you have software or hardware RAID. Disks in hardware RAID might not even be visible to your OS individually - you may see a single disk. Depending on your hardware it's impossible to give you just one answer.

The rest applies to software RAID *only*:

> How can I check, how many disks are being used for raid?

As for software raid here's a page I bookmarked a long time ago: http://www.ducea.com/2009/03/08/mdadm-cheat-sheet/

> How can I check, if all disks are healthy?
> How can I check, if any disk is being taken out or being defected?

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda # (sdb/sdc/etc)
cat /proc/mdstat
mdadm --detail /dev/md0
```

Please Google your questions first.

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment and your answer! It helped me a lot. Perhaps last question, if I remove a disk and insert a new hard disk, do I need a configuration as well or it just runs all fine?

Comment: You cannot just remove a disk and insert another one and expect everything to work. First, you 1) remove a failing disk (`mdadm --fail/--remove`), 2) attach a new one, 3) partition it and 4) add it to your RAID and then wait for it to sync.

Comment: ohhhh, ok! I just removed and inserted a new one! then the system was down! but I am doing in a lab! I hope, I can find a tutorial!